# Integrating multiple Store APIs that fulfill similar function

Tags: architecture, square, weebly

I'm working on flutter mobile app for a client. It will be a small online-shop at mobile app. They sell real products (not electronic).

The client uses Square. **As I understand, sometime ago, Square acquired Weeble. And now if you want to create online shop with Square it's working on Weeble**. But square still have they own store system to manage real-life stores.

As I see, Weeble and Square still have own api for catalog, orders, payment, and others api.

My question is do I need to use Weebly or Square, or I can use any or both of them together.

How my app will work?
I have a web admin panel and have mobile app. Plus becouse of need of more complex catalog items I'm using firebase collections with my own data structures for catalog Items.

But I don't want to create my own orders service, and inventory service.
[image]
Square has Flutter sdk, but it's only for payments as I see.

Features that I would like to have:

- check that I have Item available in store store before selling and showing items. (Inventory API on Square or Products API on Weebly). + subtract bought count of items after successful purchase
- create orders to show to the company stuff.
- show order status to users, with shipment status. (Didn't find shipment status in Square API, only in Weebly).
- Possibility to sell subcriptions with monthly payments. (Coffee subscription).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you want to avoid the added complexity of integrating multiple services if possible, as this incurs unnecessary maintenance costs.

It seems like Square is slowly adding missing features to their API that are present only on Weebly. All features you mention are available via the Square API, albeit some are still in beta. I’d imagine that once feature parity is reached the Weebly API will be deprecated as the overhead in maintaining multiple APIs that do the same thing is a waste of valuable resources.

- Inventory: https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/inventory-api
- Order creation: https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/orders-api/create-order
- Fulfillment status: https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/objects/OrderFulfillmentShipmentDetails
- Subscriptions: https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/subscriptions-api